# Viewholder of recyclerview getting called for each item

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-viewholder

I have Recyclerview in my project which is having one ViewHolder. For this RecyclerView, i have many items to populate, but for the simplicity sake, i have added 100 items. But for these 100 items **onCreateViewHolder** is being called 100 items i.e. for each item it is being called, hence for each item view is getting infalted. If i will use all items(may be 1000 or 2000), i am getting OOM. SO how can i avoid this call of **onCreateViewHolder** for each item. Really need help!!

```
public static final int HEADER = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
public static final int FOOTER = Integer.MIN_VALUE + 1;
public static final int ADAPTER_OFFSET = 2;

@Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        if (position == 0 && useHeader()) {
            return HEADER;
        }

        if (useHeader() && position > getBasicItemCount() && useFooter())
            return FOOTER;
        else if (!useHeader() && position >= getBasicItemCount() && useFooter())
            return FOOTER;

        int basicItemType = getBasicItemType(position - (useHeader() ? 1 : 0));

        if (basicItemType >= Integer.MAX_VALUE - ADAPTER_OFFSET) {
            new IllegalStateException(
                    "");
        }

        return basicItemType + ADAPTER_OFFSET;
    }

@Override
    public int getBasicItemType(int position) {
        return position;
    }
```

Comment: post your adater. Did you override `getItemViewType` ?

Comment: @Blackbelt, Thanks man, but my adapter i can't post here. Sorry for that. But it is straight forward simple adapter. I don't know what i am doing wrong. Please if you can help withour seeing the adapter

Comment: @Blackbelt yes, i have overridden getItemViewType.

Comment: and you are returning `position`?

Comment: @Blackbelt no, i am returning View Type like footer, header.

Comment: are those constants ? what is their value ?

Comment: @Blackbelt yes they are constants...

Comment: @Blackbelt i have posted my getItemViewType.

Comment: I would log how many different `basicItemType` do you have, in your getItemViewType

Comment: basicItemType returning position only. Please have a look. Edited the question.

Comment: that's the mistake. Try returning `Math.max(TYPE_FOOTER, TYPE_HEADER) + 1` instead of `basicItemType + TYPE_ADAPTEE_OFFSET;` and check if it fixes your issue

Comment: @Blackbelt added the constants value as well in the question in the top. Still should i return Math.max(TYPE_FOOTER, TYPE_HEADER) + 1 ??

Comment: the constants are irrelevant. As last return instead of `basicItemType + TYPE_ADAPTEE_OFFSET;` do `return TYPE_ADAPTEE_OFFSET`;

Comment: @Blackbelt This has solved the problem mostly. Some edit i have to do. But what was the problem. If you can explain in any answer, so that i can undertsand the concept as well as i can accept the answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`getItemViewType` changes the number of times `onCreateViewHolder` is called. The documentation states that it

> Return the view type of the item at position for the purposes of view
>   recycling.

it means that every time `getItemViewType` return a different value, Android thinks that you are dealing with a new different type, and you want a different view for it. Your implementation, is returning `position`. It means  `getItemCount`different views